# Bad base-64 in android from url retrofit

Tags: android, base64

I am getting successfully the base64 string from api, but on converting to bitmap I am facing bad base-64 exception.  I have checked the base64 string in an `online base64 string to image convertor` but there i am getting the pic perfectly. This is my code and please rectify the error.

```
observable.subscribe(new Observer<Base64Code>() {
            String base64String;

            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Base64Code value) {
                base64String = value.getCode();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

                byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64String.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching of lot of Websites, I have found that the we have to use only  the part
"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAA...";
and need to remove this "data:image/png;base64," from the string before converting to bitmap.